# Create masked array from list containing ma.masked

Tags: numpy, masked-array

If I have a (possibly multidimensional) Python list where each element is one of `True`, `False`, or `ma.masked`, what's the idiomatic way of turning this into a masked numpy array of bool?

Example:

```py
>>> print(somefunc([[True, ma.masked], [False, True]]))
[[True --]
 [False True]]
```

Comment: given an example of `ma.masked`, and the expected result.

Comment: I did add a small example of the wanted input and output.

Comment: I have not idea why you want this, or even where you get `ma.masked` from.  Yes, `np.ma.masked` is an array object used by `np.ma` code, but I don't see the point in trying to make  a list or array with it.

Comment: If you set `arr[x] = ma.masked`, that masks that slot. As for where I'm getting the values from, they're parsed from a file representing a 2D grid where one of the values matches the semantics of `np.masked` perfectly, so parsing it into a masked array directly instead of doing some inelegant multi-pass approach would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

A masked array has to attributes, `data` and `mask`:

```
In [342]: arr = np.ma.masked_array([[True, False],[False,True]])
In [343]: arr
Out[343]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[ True, False],
        [False,  True]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=True)
```

That starts without anything masked.  Then as you suggest, assigning `np.ma.masked` to an element masks the slot:

```
In [344]: arr[0,1]=np.ma.masked
In [345]: arr
Out[345]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[True, --],
        [False, True]],
  mask=[[False,  True],
        [False, False]],
  fill_value=True)
```

Here the `arr.mask` has been changed from scalar `False` (applying to the whole array) to a boolean array of `False`, and then the selected item has been changed to `True`.

`arr.data` hasn't changed:

```
In [346]: arr.data[0,1]
Out[346]: False
```

Looks like this change to `arr.mask` occurs in `data.__setitem__` at:

```
    if value is masked:
        # The mask wasn't set: create a full version.
        if _mask is nomask:
            _mask = self._mask = make_mask_none(self.shape, _dtype)
        # Now, set the mask to its value.
        if _dtype.names is not None:
            _mask[indx] = tuple([True] * len(_dtype.names))
        else:
            _mask[indx] = True
        return
```

It checks if the assignment values is this special constant, `np.ma.masked`, and it makes the full mask, and assigns `True` to an element.